# No me realiza la modificación del stock ni registra entregas

Tags: php

Estmados: quería pedir ayuda con el siguiente listado, ya que no me registra las entregas, ni me descuenta los productos entregados del stock. CUALQUIER CRÏTICA, SUGERENCIA O AYUDA ES MUY BIEN RECIBIDA. GRACIAS DESDE YA. ACLARO QUE SOY MUY NOVATO EN PHP.

Entregas

```
</head>

<body>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class= "encabezado">
            <div class="izq">
                <p>Bienvenido/a:<br><?php echo $_SESSION["nombre"]." ".$_SESSION["apellido"];?></p>
            </div>

            <div class="centro">
                <a href=principalBodega.php><img src='imagenes/home.png'><br>Home</a>
            </div>

            <div class="derecha">
                <a href="salir.php?sal=si"><img src="imagenes/cerrar.png"><br>Salir</a>
            </div>
        </div>

        <h1 align='center'>ENTREGAS REALIZADAS</h1>
        <br><br>



        <?php

            //nuevo bloque

            include('conexion.php');

            if(isset($_POST['actualiza'])){

                $seleccionar=$_POST['seleccionar'];

                $stock = $_POST['stock'];

                $consulta = "UPDATE productos SET cod_producto = '$seleccionar', stock = ('$stock' + stock) WHERE cod_producto= '$seleccionar'";

                $ejecutar=mysql_query($consulta,$conexion);
                            header("Location:mod_producto.php");


                        }else{
                            echo "<p>El producto no está registrado</p>";


            if(isset($_POST['modificar'])){
                $sel=$_POST['seleccionar'];
                $con="SELECT*FROM productos WHERE cod_producto='$sel'";
                        $ej = mysql_query($con, $conexion);
                        $res = mysql_num_rows($ej);

                        if($res>0){    

                            $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
                            $proveedor = $_POST['proveedor'];
                            $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];

                           $consulta="UPDATE productos SET descripcion='$descripcion', proveedor='$proveedor', fecha_ingreso='$fecha' WHERE cod_producto='$sel'";
                            $ejecutar=mysql_query($consulta,$conexion);
                            header("Location:mod_producto.php");

                        }else{
                            echo "<p>El producto no está registrado</p>";
                        }


            include('conexion.php');

            $consulta="SELECT * FROM entregas";
            $ejecutar=mysql_query($consulta,$conexion);

            echo "<table  width='80%' align='center'><tr>";               
            echo "<th width='20%'>RUT</th>";
            echo "<th width='20%'>CÓDIGO DEL PRODUCTO</th>";
            echo "<th width='20%'>CANTIDAD</th>";
            echo "<th width='20%'>FECHA DE ENTREGA</th>";
            echo  "</tr>"; 

            while($result=mysql_fetch_array($ejecutar)){    

              echo "<tr>";                
              echo '<td width=20%>'.$result['rut'].'</td>';
              echo '<td width=20%>'.$result['cod_producto'].'</td>';
              echo '<td width=20%>'. $result['cantidad'].'</td>';
              echo '<td width=20%>'.$result['fecha_entrega'].'</td>';
              echo "</tr>";
            }
            echo "</table></br>";



    include('conexion.php');

            if(isset($_POST['actualiza'])){

                $seleccionar=$_POST['seleccionar'];

                $stock = $_POST['stock'];

                $consulta = "UPDATE productos SET cod_producto = '$seleccionar', stock = ('$stock' + stock) WHERE cod_producto= '$seleccionar'";

                $ejecutar=mysql_query($consulta,$conexion);
                            header("Location:mod_producto.php");


                        }else{
                            echo "<p>El producto no está registrado</p>";


            if(isset($_POST['modificar'])){
                $sel=$_POST['seleccionar'];
                $con="SELECT*FROM productos WHERE cod_producto='$sel'";
                        $ej = mysql_query($con, $conexion);
                        $res = mysql_num_rows($ej);

                        if($res>0){    

                            $descripcion = $_POST['descripcion'];
                            $proveedor = $_POST['proveedor'];
                            $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];

                           $consulta="UPDATE productos SET descripcion='$descripcion', proveedor='$proveedor', fecha_ingreso='$fecha' WHERE cod_producto='$sel'";
                            $ejecutar=mysql_query($consulta,$conexion);
                            header("Location:mod_producto.php");

                        }else{
                            echo "<p>El producto no está registrado</p>";
                        }




            ?>

</body>
```

Comment: Como dato, te digo que estas utilizando una librería depreciada, deberías de estar utilizando mysqli o pdo para tus desarrollos para no darte sorpresas a futuro. Por otro lado estas actualizando el stock o el stock y el codigo, porque es lo que haces en esta linea `$consulta = "UPDATE productos SET cod_producto = '$seleccionar', stock = ('$stock' + stock) WHERE cod_producto= '$seleccionar'";` y prueba cambiado esto asi: `stock = (stock + $stock)`

Comment: No son errores pero mejorarán la calidad del programa. 1) En el primer `UPDATE` no hace falta el `cod_producto = '$seleccionar'` dentro de la claúsula `SET`, ya que no lo estás modificando. 2) Tienes que validar y sanear todos los datos proporcionados por los usuarios (mira la función [filter_var](http://php.net/manual/es/function.filter-var.php) de PHP). 3) Tienes que _escapar_ las variables que uses en sentencias SQL o mejor aun, usar _prepared statements_. 4) No mezcles código PHP y HTML. 5) Echa un vistazo a [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/).